# Specified element is already the logical child of another element.

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I gto this error when i want to add a usercontrol in a canvas .
there is a combobox when its selection changed then firslty all usercotrol in the grid are deleted through this methode :

```
       Dim childToDelete As New List(Of UIElement)
    For Each a As UIElement In gridimgFloor.Children
        childToDelete.Add(a)
    Next

    For Each c As UIElement In childToDelete
        gridimgFloor.Children.Remove(c)
    Next
```

after that is want to add new same usercontorls . but i got this error :

```
  Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
```

i am adding controls through this code :

```
         selectedFloorDevices = f.GetDevies
    For Each d As DeviceIcon In selectedFloorDevices
        Dim a As DeviceIcon = d
        'Dim a As New DeviceIcon
        Dim gr As New Canvas

        a.Rectangle.Height = f.GetDeviceScale
        a.Rectangle.Width = f.GetDeviceScale * 2

        gr.Children.Add(a)
        gridimgfloor.add(gr)
    Next
```

it gives error in this line :

```
      gr.Children.Add(a)
```

Whats the problem ? I am strugling till last 3 days but got nothing . please help.

Comment: f.GetDevies. What is f?

Comment: f is class which returns list(of DeviceIcon)

Comment: I am not familiar with VB but all elements in VisualTree are by default unique therefore you cannot insert twice the same object.

Comment: so, how can i delete a control from Visualtree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the following:

```
For Each d As DeviceIcon In selectedFloorDevices
    Dim a As DeviceIcon = d
```

You are setting a to be equal to d, remember that these are reference types, a is not a copy of d, it **is** d.

The line below is correct:

```
Dim a As New DeviceIcon
```